# Make an automatic redirect with htaccess using Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

i'm making a codeigniter-based website, but i've got a problem.

I use pretty urls with this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Everything works fine, but now i want to redirect all urls like:
- site.com/reg
- site.com/faq
- etc.
TO:
- site.com/it/reg
- site.com/it/faq
- etc.

I tried a lot of times to do this, but a see an result only using environment_status as rewritecond, but it redirect only site.com to site.com/it without redirecting urls like site.com/reg etc.

Without environment_status as rewritecond i always get an infinite redirect loop.
Any solutions?

EDIT: 
Works with

```
RewriteRule ^(reg|faq)/?$ /it/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

but is there a way to put /it/ before every request_uri without using a "whitelist" like above and without a redirect loop? (I tried put .* but there is the loop)?

SOLVED:

```
RewriteRule !^(it|index\.php) /it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Thank for the solution:

Comment: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ can be helpful with trying to figure out `.htaccess` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^(it|index\.php) /it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Good answer. One can also use a wildcard `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /it/$1` so that it works with everything and not just "faq" and "reg".

Comment: I'm not the OP. I was just adding to your answer :)

Comment: With the wildcard there is a redirect loop

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. @user2887955: Do you want everything to be redirected to `/it/` OR only selected URIs like faq, reg etc?

Comment: I want every url redirect to /it/ + the request uri. For example site.com must be redirected to site.com/it and site.com/reg must be redirected to site.com/it/reg

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.